# What's the best way to store events in a database on android?

Tags: android, database-design

I've been struggling with this problem so here is my first SO post.

I'm writing an Android app that needs to store events with seconds precision. After this data gets collected for a while, I'd like to be able to display it in a graph where the user can view this event history over time. This makes me think of using a sqlite database in android with a table with columns:

```
| eventname | timestamp |
```

Then I can get the number of each event type by counting rows in the table, and show the graph based on Last Day, Last Week, Last Month, etc. I've never worked with databases before though, so I'm not sure if this is a good approach to what I assume is a common problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A database is appropriate for this situation, but you should work through some simple database and sqlite tutorials, then come back when you hit a problem that you can describe clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the main criteria if to use database or no, it would be:
- persistance - if you want to keep the data for long period and to return to them ex. after a week or a month
- how complicated the structure is (for simplier, perhaps just an xml file would be easier, or txt file etc.)?

You don't write too much so it's difficult to advise. I believe you will have to read a lot if you have never worked with databases earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do want the data to persist over time because I'd like to show event history over past weeks, months, etc. I also have been reading on databases over the past weeks, I'm mainly wondering if this is a good approach.

Comment: Thus simply start this adventure! There is no better way to check. Database give you much more possibilities than processing ex. simple text files. It also depends how much you want to take with those data (sorting, selecting only some basing on some criteria etc.)